# C++How to Search through a Queue Array

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

I have a queue array, and I'm trying to search it to see if the desired value is in the queue. If so, move it to the front. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
queueType<string> names(100);
string name;

cout<<"Enter name: "
cin>>name;

for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
{
    if (name == names[i])
    {
         names.front(name);
    }
    else
    {
         cout<<"Name not found"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `queueType`? Without that we cannot know what member functions are there to help you in accomplishing your task.

Comment: Iteration and restructuring are not normal queue operation. Perhaps add a "move to front" operation to your queue implementation?